# Remove first zero values from string using regex

Tags: regex

I've created a string value using padStart method (padLeft), for example:

```
"5".padStart(19, "0")
```

which results into "0000000000000000005"
How can I get that 5 back using regex?
I've tested this:

```
/^0*(\d+)$/.exec(d)[1]
```

which return 5 correctly.

But this regex returns null for something like "00000012.22"

Samples:

5 > 5

005 > 5

0011.22 > 11.22 >> This is a first problem!

00100 >> 100

001001 >> 1001

**00.5 >> 0.5** This is a second problem!

Working codes but without regex:

```
function toDb(d) {
        if (d == null) return null;
        var precisionIndex = d.indexOf('.');
        return d.toString().padStart((29 + precisionIndex + 1), '0');
        }

function fromDb(d) {
            if (d == null) return null;
            d = d.replace(/^0+/, ''); // I'd like to use regex here
            if (d.indexOf('.') == 0) // I'd like to use regex here
                d = '0' + d; // I'd like to use regex here
            return d;
    }
```

fromDb(toDb('0.5')) returns 0.5 for me. But I'd like to use regex in my codes.

Comment: Actually, there is a regex to deal with that kind of tasks, but - if you want to make it really comprehensible - it will be very long and rather unweildly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace leading `0`.

```js
console.log(
  "0000000000000000005".replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '')
)

console.log(
  "000000000000000000.5".replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '')
)
```

In the regex [start anchor(`^`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)  assert the beginning position of the string and `0+` matches combination [one or more repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of `0`, altogether `^0+` matches `0`s at the beginning.

**UPDATE :** To avoid removing `0` just before the `.` use [positive look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?=\d)` match up to the `0` which follows a digit.

Comment: 007 makes a better test string.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer + It's four time faster (-: Thanks for your details information.